I need help writing a test for a trigger on OpportunityLineItem
I recently attempted my first trigger to update some of the fields on Opportunity from product details on OpportunityLineItem. The trigger works fine but I cannot deploy it because I haven't managed to succesfully create a test that works.
This is my test.  I have struggled massively with creating the Opportunity record because I need a PriceList and found it impossible to create a price list entry for a standard price. If I create a price liste entry is wants me to create a standard one first, but when I try to set IsStandard to true it says I cannot set it.
@isTest
public class UpdateProfessionalServicesTotalTest {
    @isTest
    static void testUpdateProfessionalServicesTotal() {
        // Ensure the Standard Price Book is available and active
        Pricebook2 standardPricebook;
        List<Pricebook2> pbList = [SELECT Id FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsStandard = true LIMIT 1];
        if (pbList.isEmpty()) {
            standardPricebook = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Standard Price Book', IsActive = true);
            insert standardPricebook;
        } else {
            standardPricebook = pbList[0];
        }

        System.assertNotEquals(null, standardPricebook, 'Standard Pricebook not found or created');

        // Create a test product with Product Family 'Professional Services' and add it to the Standard Price Book
        Product2 professionalServicesProduct = new Product2(Name = 'Test Professional Services Product', Family = 'Professional Services', IsActive = true);
        insert professionalServicesProduct;

        // Create the standard price entry
        PricebookEntry standardProfessionalServicesPBE = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = standardPricebook.Id,
            Product2Id = professionalServicesProduct.Id,
            UnitPrice = 500.0,
            IsActive = true,
            Cost__c = 1.0,
            UseStandardPrice = true
        );
        insert standardProfessionalServicesPBE;

        // Create a test product with a different Product Family and add it to the Standard Price Book
        Product2 otherProduct = new Product2(Name = 'Test Other Product', Family = 'Other', IsActive = true);
        insert otherProduct;

        // Create the standard price entry for the other product
        PricebookEntry standardOtherPBE = new PricebookEntry(
            Pricebook2Id = standardPricebook.Id,
            Product2Id = otherProduct.Id,
            UnitPrice = 300.0,
            IsActive = true,
            Cost__c = 1.0,
            UseStandardPrice = true
        );
        insert standardOtherPBE;

        // Create a test Opportunity with the Standard Price Book
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name = 'Test Opportunity', CloseDate = Date.today(), StageName = 'Prospecting', Pricebook2Id = standardPricebook.Id);
        insert opp;

        // Ensure the Opportunity is inserted before adding OpportunityLineItems
        opp = [SELECT Id, Pricebook2Id, Professional_Services__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(standardPricebook.Id, opp.Pricebook2Id);

        // Add OpportunityLineItem with Professional Services product
        OpportunityLineItem oli1 = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = opp.Id,
            PricebookEntryId = standardProfessionalServicesPBE.Id,
            Quantity = 1,
            UnitPrice = 500.0,
            TotalPrice = 500.0
        );
        insert oli1;

        // Verify the Professional_Services__c field on Opportunity is updated
        opp = [SELECT Id, Professional_Services__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(500.0, opp.Professional_Services__c);

        // Add another OpportunityLineItem with a different product family
        OpportunityLineItem oli2 = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = opp.Id,
            PricebookEntryId = standardOtherPBE.Id,
            Quantity = 1,
            UnitPrice = 300.0,
            TotalPrice = 300.0
        );
        insert oli2;

        // Verify the Professional_Services__c field on Opportunity remains the same
        opp = [SELECT Id, Professional_Services__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(500.0, opp.Professional_Services__c);

        // Update the OpportunityLineItem with Professional Services product
        oli1.TotalPrice = 800.0;
        update oli1;

        // Verify the Professional_Services__c field on Opportunity is updated
        opp = [SELECT Id, Professional_Services__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(800.0, opp.Professional_Services__c);

        // Delete the OpportunityLineItem with Professional Services product
        delete oli1;

        // Verify the Professional_Services__c field on Opportunity is updated
        opp = [SELECT Id, Professional_Services__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(0.0, opp.Professional_Services__c);

        // Add OpportunityLineItem with Professional Services product again
        oli1 = new OpportunityLineItem(
            OpportunityId = opp.Id,
            PricebookEntryId = standardProfessionalServicesPBE.Id,
            Quantity = 1,
            UnitPrice = 800.0,
            TotalPrice = 800.0
        );
        insert oli1;

        // Verify the Professional_Services__c field on Opportunity is updated
        opp = [SELECT Id, Professional_Services__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(800.0, opp.Professional_Services__c);
    }
}

The error I am currently getting is:

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, Before creating a custom price, create a standard price.: []
Stack Trace:
Class.UpdateProfessionalServicesTotalTest.testUpdateProfessionalServicesTotal: line 30, column 1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UseStandardPrice = true  is a catch-22 when what you're trying to do is create an entry in the standard pricebook for this product. It needs to be false

Testing OpportunityLineItem is a bit of a pain.
I think you were on the right track with trying to fetch the Standard Price Book, but doing the insert isn't quite what you want to do here. Salesforce will always treat that as a custom price book rather than the (one) standard pricebook that everyone gets.
In test contexts, you can use Test.getStandardPricebookId() instead of trying to query for the pricebook (and trying to insert if it isn't found).
Alternatively, The Pricebook2 Name field has a special property called "idLookup" (which is documented in the object reference for Pricebook2). That basically means we can use it as an external id.
Provided that the Pricebook2 names are unique in your org, you could do
List<Pricebook2> pricebooks = new List<Pricebook2>();
pricebooks.add(new Pricebook2(Name = 'Standard Price Book'));

// Also works magnificently with custom pricebooks
//pricebooks.add(new Pricebook2(Name = 'My Custom Pricebook'));

// This is the key, using upsert and specifying the "external id" field to use
//   to determine whether or not it's an insert or an update.
// This is enough to get past Salesforce's nonsense with Pricebooks not being
//   queryable before being updated
upsert pricebooks Name;

// The pricebook(s) are now queryable (whereas before the upsert, the query
//   would return 0 rows)
List<Pricebook2> queriedPricebooks = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Pricebook2];

